# What should the controller name be for this route?

Tags: ember.js

I have the following route:

"get-started"

However when I create a file named "get_started_controller" in app/controllers (ember app kit) it doesn't seem to be picking up this controller.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  personName: "set";

  actions: {
    letsDesign: function() {
      alert('hi');
    }
  }

});
```

it says "nothing handled the action 'letsDesign' when I have a button bound to that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think the file name needs `_controller`, just `get_started.js`